# Turn Off Auto-Renewal For a Specific Member

Tags: civimember, auto-renew

I was sure I knew how to do this but now I am not finding the solution so I apologize if this is right in front of me.  We have memberships that we want people to have auto-renewal for but sometimes we need to turn it off for a specific member.  I do not see a way to turn off auto-renew from the admin interface for a single member.

I know it is on for the member because I see this:
[image]

This is what I see if I edit the member:
[image]

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have you had a look on the contribution tab rather than the membership tab.

Comment: there should be a sub-tab relating to recurring payments

Comment: whether you can disable from there such that it also stops at the payment processor end may depend on the payment processor

Comment: actually i just set one up on dmaster and on the 'edit membership' i see this at the top "This membership is set to renew automatically . Please be aware that any changes that you make here may not be reflected in the payment processor. Please ensure that you alter the related subscription at the payment processor.
To stop the automatic renewal: Cancel auto-renew (link)"

Comment: currently here but won't be once the site gets its daily rebuild: https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view/membership?action=update&reset=1&cid=203&id=31&context=membership&selectedChild=member

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, turns thank you! I was testing on a pay latter contribution. It makes sense that even if auto-renewal is on it would only work (and therefore be able to cancel it) if it is a credit card transaction.

Answer (score 2):

If a membership is auto-renew than it should be linked to recurring contribution(See under contribution tab >> recurring tab).

To turn off auto-renew for a membership, you can either

1. Cancel the recurring, that should cancel ongoing recurring payment and also membership renewal
2. Run Below query to only turn off membership renewal

Sql:

```
UPDATE civicrm_membership SET contribution_recur_id = NULL WHERE id = 123;
```

HTH

Pradeep